# Properties of $\mathsf{PH}[1]$ and $\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{poly(n)}[1]$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, space-complexity

$\mathsf{PH}[1]$ is a variant of a polynomial hierarchy in which each machine can only call its oracle once. $\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{poly(n)}[1]$ is a polynomially "tall" tower of $\mathsf{NP}[1]$ oracles. Each of these oracles can accept an input no longer than $n+o(n)$.

Quite trivially, $\mathsf{PH}[1]\subseteq\mathsf{PH}$ and $\mathsf{PH}[1]\subseteq\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{poly(n)}[1]$. However, what are some less trivial properties? E.g. does

$$\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{poly(n)}[1]=\mathsf{PSPACE}$$

imply that $\mathsf P=\mathsf{NP}\Rightarrow\mathsf P=\mathsf{PSPACE}$? I assume this because I imagine a $\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{poly(n)}[1]$ program would look as something like (the stack supports only polynomially deep recursion):

```
routine(input):
  for i in range(poly(n)):
    input' = //{do something with input}
  routine(input')
  for i in range(poly(n)):
    result = //{do something}
  return result
```

I.e. it would be of a polynomial depth with no branching, therefore the whole computation subroutine call tree would have just polynomially many edges.

What about consequences of either $\mathsf{PH}[1]=\mathsf{PH}$ or $\mathsf{PH}[1]\subsetneq\mathsf{PH}$? Quite similarly, are there any consequences of $\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_{m+k}[1]=\Sigma^{\mathsf P}_k$ for some constants $m$ and $k$?